# WPF TextBox SpellChecking Problem

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, wpf-controls, spell-checking

How can I change the spellchecking language of a WPF textbox to french using XAML?
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="true" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true" FontSize="12" BorderBrush="Blue" Height="100" Language="fr-fr" />
```

French is supposed to be one of the 4 supported languages for spellchecking in WPF so I don't understand why it doesn't work. I also tried fr-CA but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need resource file of .Net Framework for the language you want to activate…

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the XML language attribute. For me, this actually worked:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="true" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true" FontSize="12" BorderBrush="Blue" Height="100" xml:lang="fr" />
```